# How to read json properties using PHP

Tags: php, json

How to get all pid and styles attribute from following json data with minimum loop in php

```
{"general":{"note":{"display":false}},"elements":{"the-1":{"index":1,"src":"shirt1.png","pid":"pid-3563130","angle":0,"styles":"background:transparent;top:51.80000305175781px;left:122px;width:80px;height:80px;","background":"transparent","pos":{"top":51.80000305175781,"left":122},"size":{"width":80,"height":80},"details":{"other":""}},"the-2":{"index":2,"src":"shirt2.png","pid":"pid-132002","angle":0,"styles":"background:transparent;top:44.80000305175781px;left:155px;width:80px;height:80px;","background":"transparent","pos":{"top":44.80000305175781,"left":155},"size":{"width":80,"height":80},"details":{"other":""}}}}
```

Thanks

Comment: this *MUST* be a duplicate of something

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly do you want to know? Do you have problems parsing JSON? Or with accessing arrays? Or with iterating over an array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON Decode in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616880/json-decode-in-php)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$str = '{"general":{"note":{"display":false}},"elements":{"the-1":{"index":1,"src":"shirt1.png","pid":"pid-3563130","angle":0,"styles":"background:transparent;top:51.80000305175781px;left:122px;width:80px;height:80px;","background":"transparent","pos":{"top":51.80000305175781,"left":122},"size":{"width":80,"height":80},"details":{"other":""}},"the-2":{"index":2,"src":"shirt2.png","pid":"pid-132002","angle":0,"styles":"background:transparent;top:44.80000305175781px;left:155px;width:80px;height:80px;","background":"transparent","pos":{"top":44.80000305175781,"left":155},"size":{"width":80,"height":80},"details":{"other":""}}}}';

$arr = json_decode($str, true);

foreach ($arr['elements'] as $element) {
    echo 'pid: ' . $element['pid'] . '<br />';
    echo 'styles: ' . $element['styles'] . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use json_decode function in PHP to get assosiative array.

```
<?php
    $myJson = '{"general":{"note":{"display":false}},"elements":{"the-1":{"index":1,"src":"shirt1.png","pid":"pid-3563130","angle":0,"styles":"background:transparent;top:51.80000305175781px;left:122px;width:80px;height:80px;","background":"transparent","pos":{"top":51.80000305175781,"left":122},"size":{"width":80,"height":80},"details":{"other":""}},"the-2":{"index":2,"src":"shirt2.png","pid":"pid-132002","angle":0,"styles":"background:transparent;top:44.80000305175781px;left:155px;width:80px;height:80px;","background":"transparent","pos":{"top":44.80000305175781,"left":155},"size":{"width":80,"height":80},"details":{"other":""}}}}';  
    $myArray = json_decode($myJson,true);
    $myInnerArray = $myArray['elements'];
    $styles = array();
    foreach($myInnerArray as $element)
       $styles[] = $element['styles'];
    print_r($styles);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has great abilities to handle json.

Let's assume the JSON string you've posted above is stored in a PHP variable `$myJSON`.

So we can easily store an associative array of these values into `$myJSONArray` like so:

```
$myJSONArray = json_decode( $myJSON, true );
```

So, now we just loop through:

```
foreach( $myJSONArray['elements'] as $arr => $key )
     echo( "A PID: " . $key['pid'] . "\n" );
```

See it in action on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/AWqvRwQz).

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = json_decode('{"general":{"note":{"display":false}},"elements":{"the-1":{"index":1,"src":"shirt1.png","pid":"pid-3563130","angle":0,"styles":"background:transparent;top:51.80000305175781px;left:122px;width:80px;height:80px;","background":"transparent","pos":{"top":51.80000305175781,"left":122},"size":{"width":80,"height":80},"details":{"other":""}},"the-2":{"index":2,"src":"shirt2.png","pid":"pid-132002","angle":0,"styles":"background:transparent;top:44.80000305175781px;left:155px;width:80px;height:80px;","background":"transparent","pos":{"top":44.80000305175781,"left":155},"size":{"width":80,"height":80},"details":{"other":""}}}}', true);
$elements = $json['elements'];
foreach($elements as $element){
    $pid = $element['pid'];
    $styles = $element['styles'];
    echo $pid.': '.$styles.'<br />';
}
```

[***Example here***](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cqtLrW)