# Get value of JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I'm a beginner on php.
This document is the result of a mongodb query.

```
Array ( [_id] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 55e994585bab8c0a816e0693 ) [metadata] => Array ( [timestamp] => 1441371224596 ) [message] => Array ( [itsPduHeader] => Array ( [messageID] => 1 [protocolVersion] => 1 [stationId] => 33000 ) [denm] => Array ( [managementContainer] => Array ( [relevanceDistance] => 3 [referenceTime] => 363373455171 [stationType] => 15 [actionID] => Array ( [sequenceNumber] => 69 [orignatorStationID] => 33000 ) [detectionTime] => 363373438142 [eventPosition] => Array ( [altitude] => Array ( [altitudeValue] => 0 [altitudeConfidence] => 15 ) [posConfidenceEllipse] => Array ( [semiMajorOrientation] => 3601 [semiMinorConfidence] => 4095 [semiMajorConfidence] => 4095 ) [latitude] => 448848419 [longitude] => -5615145 ) ) [situationContainer] => Array ( [informationQuality] => 0 [eventType] => Array ( [subCauseCodeType] => 0 [causeCodeType] => 1 ) ) [locationContainer] => Array ( [traces] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [pathPosition] => Array ( [deltaAltitude] => 0 [deltaLongitude] => 0 [deltaLatitude] => 0 ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

But I can't get the value of latitude and longitude.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read json properties using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279585/how-to-read-json-properties-using-php)

Comment: We need to decode the JSON value.

check this URL
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429029/php-get-values-from-json-encode][1]

Comment: it's not all ready decoded?

Comment: $doc = json_decode($doc, true); returns NULL

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-returnvalues if in doubt check the doc

Comment: Looking at your question more you seem to actually be referencing "JSON" as the returned serialised object from the MongoDB query, which it is not. It is now a primitive object, a.k.a an array, as you're var_dump shows. Check this doc URL for array accession in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: The problem is resolved i use:
$doc["message"]["denm"]["managementContainer"]["eventPosition"]["latitude"]
to get the value of latitude for exemple
thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$result = array();
echo $result['message']['denm']['managementContainer']['eventPosition']['latitude'];
echo $result['message']['denm']['managementContainer']['eventPosition']['longitude'];
```