# How to parse the json_decode to string if i obtain all output

Tags: php, json

I need obtain the data from this output for example. It's `json_decode`:

> [{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"admin","usuario":"admin","2":"admin","clave":"admin","3":"Juan","nombre":"Juan","4":"Sepulveda","apellido":"Sepulveda","5":"25","edad":"25"},{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"user","usuario":"user","2":"123456","clave":"123456","3":"Jose","nombre":"Jose","4":"Gonzalez","apellido":"Gonzalez","5":"34","edad":"34"},{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"rowso","usuario":"rowso","2":"rowso","clave":"rowso","3":"Juanito","nombre":"Juanito","4":"Sepulveda","apellido":"Sepulveda","5":"25","edad":"25"},{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"nuevo","usuario":"nuevo","2":"123","clave":"123","3":"nuevo","nombre":"nuevo","4":"yourmeh","apellido":"yourmeh","5":"58","edad":"58"}]

For example:

```
string id = jsonblabla.getstring(id);
```

This is my code in php to get the json_decode:

```
<?php
include_once("conexion.php"); 
// sentencia a consultar
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
// asignar la consulta al gesto de mysql
if($resultado = mysqli_multi_query($conn,$consulta));
{
  do
    {
    // Store first result set
    if ($resultado=mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
      // Fetch one and one row
      while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
        {
        $flag[] = $fila;
        }
      // Free result set
      print(json_encode($flag));
      }
    }
  while (mysqli_next_result($conn));
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: If you want to read json properties using PHP then this question is duplicate, see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279585/how-to-read-json-properties-using-php

Comment: Do you want to get this information to your webpage (as your example seems to be about javascript)? Please clarify your question.

Comment: If you want to get the information accessible in PHP, then using `json_encode()` returns a string.  If your example is what is output from your SQL query, its elements should already be accessible in PHP from it.  `json_encode()` returns the string representation of an associative array.

Comment: i need transform the json obtain in attributes in java

i received this code in String

 [{"id":"1","usuario":"admin","clave":"admin","nombre":"Juan","apellido":"Sepulveda","edad":"25"}]

for example  String id = string obtain;

or converter the string obtain in array or object to use.

String message = "hello"+id;