# How to format json response in php before echoing it out in js file

Tags: php, json

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

this is the result

```
{"response":"1", "name":"john", "id":22, "again":0, "text":xe};
```

Before echoing it in the js file via ajax I want to format it so I only get the data which i want to use which is id and name but its outputting the wrog data

```
$data = array();
$data[] = array("id"=>$result.'id', "name"=>$result.'name');
echo $data;
```

data it prints

```
( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1id and so on
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7279618/5209435). You won't need the loop but it should give you an idea of how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you want result become an object do below

> $obj = json_decode($result);

if you want resualt become an array do below

> $arr = json_decode($result , true);

```
echo $obj->name;
echo $arr['name'];
```

Comment: For some reason '$arr = json_decode($result , true);'  After than echoing arr gives the output 1 
print_r($arr);

Same thing happens when i use $obj = json_decode($result);

Comment: what you want to echo should be as this -->echo $arr['name'];